# AngularJS - Updating variables within the parent controller scope from a function in a transcluded directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, transclusion, angularjs-ng-transclude

**How are parent controller scope variables updated from within a transcluded directive scope's function?**

I am embedding directives into another directive using a transclusion in the following manner:

```
<my-table>
  <my-getter-button></my-getter-button>
</my-table>
```

The code for my-table and my-getter-button follows:

**`my-table` template:**

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td data-id="{{item.Id}}" ng-transclude></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**`my-table` directive:**

```
.directive('myTable', function () {
      return {
          transclude: true,
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'views/mytable.html',
          scope: false
      };
  });
```

**`my-getter-button` directive (with template):**

```
app.directive('myGetterButton', function () {
    function link(scope, element) {
        scope.finalizeGet = function () {
            var id = element.parent().data('id');
            scope.clear();  // <-- works fine (from parent controller)
            scope.get(id)  // <-- works fine (from parent controller)
            .success(function (data) {
                // The line below was supposed to 
                // update the variables within the parent controller:
                scope.$parent.instance = data; // or scope.instance = data;
                angular.element('#detailsModal').modal('show');
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                scope.errors = data;
            });
        };
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="finalizeGet()">' +
                      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>' +
                  '</button>',
        scope: false,
        link: link
    };
});
```

I was expecting `scope.$parent.instance = data; // or scope.instance = data;` to change the parent controller's `scope.instance` but it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my own problem.
Turns out what I needed was a setter function.
I added the following in my controller:

```
// Set current model instance of scope.
$scope.setInstance = function(data) {
  $scope.instance = data;
};
```

And called the setter function (instead of having an assignment operation), as follows:

```
// ...
.success(function (data) {
  scope.setInstance(data);
  angular.element('#detailsModal').modal('show');
})
// ...
```

It updated the variable in the parent controller scope.